# Which floor tiling pattern is more challenging for a relatively straight floor and larger tiles, staggered (1/3) or straight set?

Tags: tiling, design, layout

So here is the final design I would like to implement.
The small shelves to the left of the toilet are designed to conceal the main stack and to constructively  use the space that left between the main stack and the wall.

[image]

The other option would be a staggered pattern which seems a little bit too busy
Please ignore the imperfections in this second picture (like that small uncovered strip near the shower base)
[image]

Comment: bottom diagram ... looking in from doorway ... rightmost row is out of sequence

Comment: have you considered diagonal patterns? ... herringbone patterns?

Comment: Noo those will not match the wall patern at all

Comment: Larger  tiles staggered half way can be problematic because the center of the tile has a slight camber and will cause lippage when set alongside an end of the adjacent tile.  1/3 stagger is recommended rather than 1/2

Comment: 1/3 or 1/2 stagger has an advantage that if any of the walls, shower, etc. are not totally parallel/perpendicular then it will not be as noticeable as with a straight line of tiles.

Comment: It is an opinion based question so in my opinion staggered looks better

Comment: @kris it is not about what is better looking but which one is more techically challenging to do right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option is definitely more challenging due to the added tile cuts needed to stagger the tile.

As far as being too busy, once it's grouting in, it will look fine and will show a little imagination and craftsmanship.

Comment: I think it depends on the tile. In my case it will be https://www.lafabbrica.it/prodotto/lascaux/  (the Kimberly model ) That tile looks good in one piece and not that good when cut

Comment: @minime “it’s not about how it looks“ you said. This is an answer to the degree if difficulty

Answer (score 0):

It is personal choice, but large square or rectangular tile in a smallish room will not look "good" if placed parallel to the walls. I have 12" square tiles, in a large kitchen they look fine. But for two small bathrooms, the tile guy said they should be at 45 angle. We did the 45 and it looks good. It sounds like extra cutting but for our square tile, a corner to corner cut gives you two pieces.  It looked so good that when I did two larger rooms with 18" square tile, I set them at 45 degrees, cutting was no big deal with diamond blade.

Comment: The opinions differ just google it, my cousin has smaller bathrooms then the one I am doing and they both look Ok with large tiles.

Comment: Agin this is not about what looks better as in `on my taste` but rather which one is more challenging to make it look right. There will be wall imperfections and mistakes